# How to stop setInterval in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
/*front design: dribbble https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/85456/screenshots/3996869/artboard_3_1x.png*/
var audio = new Audio('http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1377&type=mp3');
var pomodoro = 25,
  currentTime = Date.parse(new Date()),
  deadline, timeInterval, breakTime = 5,
  i;

function beep() {
  audio.play();
}

var count = $('.sl').find('h2').text();

var count1 = $('.bl').find('h2').text();
//console.log(count1);
function plus() {
  count++;
  $('.sl2').text(count);
  $('.timer').text(count + ":00");
  pomodoro = $('.sl').find('h2').text();

}

function minus() {
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    $('.sl2').text(count);
    $('.timer').text(count + ":00");
    pomodoro = $('.sl').find('h2').text();
    //console.log(pomodoro);
  }
}

function plus1() {
  count1++;
  $('.bl2').text(count1);
  breakTime++;

}

function minus1() {
  if (count1 > 1) {
    count1--;
    //beep();
    breakTime--;
    $('.bl2').text(count1);
    //console.log(breakTime);

  }
}


function getTimeLeft(end) {
  var total = Date.parse(end) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);

  return {
    "total": total,
    "minutes": minutes,
    "seconds": seconds
  };
}

function startClock() {
  timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var t = getTimeLeft(deadline);

    $(".timer").html(("0" + t.minutes).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + t.seconds).slice(-2));

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      beep(); //If timer reaches zero, stop the timer.
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
      if (i === 0) {
        startBreak();
      } else if (i === 1) {
        startPomodoro();
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function startPomodoro() {
  deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + (pomodoro * 60 * 1000));
  //alert(deadline);
  startClock();
  i = 1;
}

function startBreak() {
  deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + (breakTime * 60 * 1000)); //Set deadline
  startClock();
  i = 0;
}

$('.btn_start').click(function() {
  $(".change").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  startPomodoro();

});
$('.btn_break').click(function() {
  $(".change").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $('.session').text('BREAK');
  startBreak();
});
$('.cplus').click(function() {
  //console.log('b12');
  plus1();
});
$('.cminus').click(function() {
  //console.log('b12');
  minus1();
});
$('.bplus').click(function() {
  //console.log('b12');
  plus();
});
$('.bminus').click(function() {
  //console.log('b12');
  minus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Just a</h1>
    <h1>Pomodoro</h1>
    <h3><a href="https://codepen.io/chintuyadav" target="_blank">Coded by Chintu Yadav Sara</a> </h3>
    <h3>Freecodecamp.org</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="screen">
      <h3 class="session">SESSION</h3>
      <h1 class="timer">25:00</h1>
      <button class="btn btn_start">Start</button> <button class="btn btn_break">Take Break</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="bl">
        <input class="change cplus" id="bl2+" type="button" value="+"><input class="change cminus" id="bl2-" type="button" value="-">
        <h2 class="bl2">5</h2>
        <p class="bl1">Break length</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sl">
        <input class="change bplus" id="sl2+" type="button" value="+"><input class="change bminus" id="sl2-" type="button" value="-">
        <h2 class="sl2">25</h2>
        <p class="sl1">Session length</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble with the code. When I try to run the code. It's running properly but after the execution it again starts. Even though I tried to **clearInterval()** . When I click startPomodor() it is starting properly and after completion again it is starting. So, How could I stop the execution of the code. Here is the code for that.

Comment: It will always restart because of this... `if (i === 1) { startPomodoro(); }`

Comment: True Archer. Any reason the code needs this if?

Comment: so, how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add "if (i === 0) {" after the clearInterval? It will start the counter again. The clearInterval just stop executing the code, but it will go through the existing code.

Just remove this from you JS code:

```
if (i === 0) {
        startBreak();
      } else if (i === 1) {
        startPomodoro();
      }
```

Do you have any reason for it? You dont need to execute the setInterval, it executes every 1000 milliseconds until you clear it.

You can read more about this here:

[w3school - setinterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

[w3school - clearinterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: there are two options names take break and start pomodoro. so i added .

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Start a new "promodo" timer after a break? You set the needed timer and press the button. What will the next step after the timer is reach the zero?

Comment: it has to stop.

Comment: Just remove the if, what I wrote in the answer, it will stop and now restart the interval again. You dont need the add the startPomodoro() in the setInterval, because it execute the inner code infinite times until you clear it. ClearInterval says to the setInterval that this will be the last runtime.